# Hide/Show Toggle Jquery

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

My paragraphs need to be hidden at first and I do not know how to hide it when the page loads.

I am using toggle jquery to expand/hide my paragraph. How can I achieve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#toggle").click(function () {
        $("#expand").toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="expand">Small or large business look no further for an office cleaning company in Raleigh. Feel confident that commercial cleaning services will get the job done right. Call or contact us today for a quote.</p>

<button id="toggle">Hide/Expand</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried bootstrap? See example here. This might help you. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Comment: I have not but thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide it initially with CSS:

```
p#expand {
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But it is only effecting one paragraph in a series of columns. Other columns are not showing. I have attached the id=expand with the others what can be the issue?

Comment: use a css class instead of an id (you can only have one element with a given id): <p class='hide'>lorem ipsum</p>, then in your stylesheet: p.hide { display: none; }

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#expand").hide();
    $("#toggle").on('click', function(){
        $("#expand").toggle('slow');
    })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <script 
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
   </script> 
    <title></title> 
  </head> 
  <body> 


  <p id="expand">Small or large business look no further for an office cleaning company in Raleigh. Feel confident that commercial cleaning services will get the job done right. Call or contact us today for a quote.</p>

 <button id="toggle">Hide/Expand</button>
 </body> 
 </html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <script 
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
   </script> 
    <title></title> 
  </head> 
  <body> 


  <p id="expand">Small or large business look no further for an office cleaning company in Raleigh. Feel confident that commercial cleaning services will get the job done right. Call or contact us today for a quote.</p>

 <button id="toggle">Hide/Expand</button>
 </body> 
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#expand").hide();
    $("#toggle").on('click', function(){
        $("#expand").toggle('slow');
    })
});

</script>
</html>
```